# How to add "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header in yaws to cacheable files

Tags: http-headers, erlang, yaws, http-accept-encoding

I was testing my website for optimization and I got this recommendation:

```
The following publicly cacheable, compressible resources should have a "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header:
```

So, How do I add `Vary: Accept-Encoding` header using an embedded yaws to css and js files?

I am an arg_rewrite_mod I believe I should do something from there but i am not quite sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [**yaws.hyber.org**](http://yaws.hyber.org/):
Yaws will add **`Accept-Encoding`** in **`Vary`** header if the support of gzip compression is enabled or if the response is compressed.
The **`Vary`** header can be set using **`yaws:outh_set_vary(Fields)`** or by returning **`{header, {vary, Fields}}`** from scripts (where Fields is a list of header names).